# Getting OpenCL on Google Pixel 2 XL?

Tags: android, opencl

I am working on an app specifically for the Pixel 2 XL. I want to use OpenCL on it, but it looks like that the OpenCL libraries are not on the device. Curiously GeekBench shows a OpenCL score for it.

What do I have to do to get OpenCL working on it? I've also obtained the Adreno 540 SDK, but I can't find OpenCL in that either. As a secondary goal, I'm trying to get the Qt Video filters demo working on it.

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/examples/multimedia/video/qmlvideofilter_opencl

> GLES: Qualcomm, Adreno (TM) 540, OpenGL ES 3.2 V@258.0 (GIT@594927b, I916dfac403) (Date:10/11/17)

https://browser.geekbench.com/android_devices/388

```
taimen:/system/lib $ ls -1 lib*
lib-imsvideocodec.so
lib-imsvt.so
lib-imsvtextutils.so
lib-imsvtutils.so
libEGL.so
libETC1.so
libFFTEm.so
libGLESv1_CM.so
libGLESv2.so
libGLESv3.so
libOpenMAXAL.so
libOpenSLES.so
libRS.so
libRSCacheDir.so
libRSCpuRef.so
libRSDriver.so
libRS_internal.so
libRScpp.so
libaaudio.so
libaaudioservice.so
libandroid.so
libandroid_net.so
libandroid_runtime.so
libandroid_servers.so
libandroidfw.so
libappfuse.so
libart-compiler.so
libart-dexlayout.so
libart.so
libaudio-resampler.so
libaudioclient.so
libaudioeffect_jni.so
libaudioflinger.so
libaudiohal.so
libaudiomanager.so
libaudiopolicyenginedefault.so
libaudiopolicymanager.so
libaudiopolicymanagerdefault.so
libaudiopolicyservice.so
libaudioprocessing.so
libaudiospdif.so
libaudioutils.so
libbacktrace.so
libbase.so
libbcinfo.so
libbinder.so
libblas.so
libc++.so
libc.so
libc_malloc_debug.so
libcamera2ndk.so
libcamera_client.so
libcamera_metadata.so
libcameraservice.so
libchrome.so
libclcore.bc
libclcore_debug.bc
libclcore_debug_g.bc
libclcore_g.bc
libclcore_neon.bc
libcompiler_rt.so
libcrypto.so
libcutils.so
libdebuggerd_client.so
libdiag_system.so
libdl.so
libdmengine.so
libdmjavaplugin.so
libdng_sdk.so
libdrmframework.so
libdrmframework_jni.so
libdvr.so
libdvr_loader.so
libeaselcomm.so
libeffectsconfig.so
libevent.so
libexif.so
libexpat.so
libfilterfw.so
libfilterpack_facedetect.so
libfilterpack_imageproc.so
libfmq.so
libfrsdk.so
libft2.so
libgatekeeper.so
libgraphicsenv.so
libgui.so
libhardware.so
libhardware_legacy.so
libharfbuzz_ng.so
libheif.so
libhidlbase.so
libhidlmemory.so
libhidltransport.so
libhwbinder.so
libhwui.so
libicui18n.so
libicuuc.so
libimg_utils.so
libimscamera_jni.so
libimsmedia_jni.so
libinput.so
libinputflinger.so
libinputservice.so
libiprouteutil.so
libjavacore.so
libjavacrypto.so
libjnigraphics.so
libjpeg.so
libkeystore_binder.so
libldacBT_abr.so
libldacBT_enc.so
liblog.so
liblz4.so
liblzma.so
libm.so
libmdnssd.so
libmedia.so
libmedia_helper.so
libmedia_jni.so
libmedia_omx.so
libmediadrm.so
libmedialogservice.so
libmediametrics.so
libmediandk.so
libmediaplayerservice.so
libmediautils.so
libmemtrack.so
libmemunreachable.so
libmidi.so
libminikin.so
libmtp.so
libnativebridge.so
libnativehelper.so
libnativeloader.so
libnativewindow.so
libnbaio.so
libnetd_client.so
libnetlink.so
libnetutils.so
libneuralnetworks.so
libnl.so
libopenjdk.so
libopenjdkjvm.so
libopenjdkjvmti.so
libopus.so
libpac.so
libpackagelistparser.so
libpcre2.so
libpdfium.so
libpiex.so
libpixelflinger.so
libpng.so
libpower.so
libpowermanager.so
libprocessgroup.so
libprocinfo.so
libprotobuf-cpp-full.so
libprotobuf-cpp-lite.so
libradio_metadata.so
librcc.so
libresourcemanagerservice.so
librs_jni.so
librtp_jni.so
libschedulerservicehidl.so
libselinux.so
libsensor.so
libsensorservice.so
libsensorservicehidl.so
libserviceutility.so
libsigchain.so
libskia.so
libsoftkeymaster.so
libsonic.so
libsonivox.so
libsoundpool.so
libsoundtrigger.so
libsoundtriggerservice.so
libspeexresampler.so
libsqlite.so
libssl.so
libstagefright.so
libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
libstagefright_enc_common.so
libstagefright_flacdec.so
libstagefright_foundation.so
libstagefright_http_support.so
libstagefright_httplive.so
libstagefright_omx.so
libstagefright_omx_utils.so
libstagefright_soft_aacdec.so
libstagefright_soft_aacenc.so
libstagefright_soft_amrdec.so
libstagefright_soft_amrnbenc.so
libstagefright_soft_amrwbenc.so
libstagefright_soft_avcdec.so
libstagefright_soft_avcenc.so
libstagefright_soft_flacdec.so
libstagefright_soft_flacenc.so
libstagefright_soft_g711dec.so
libstagefright_soft_gsmdec.so
libstagefright_soft_hevcdec.so
libstagefright_soft_mp3dec.so
libstagefright_soft_mpeg2dec.so
libstagefright_soft_mpeg4dec.so
libstagefright_soft_mpeg4enc.so
libstagefright_soft_opusdec.so
libstagefright_soft_rawdec.so
libstagefright_soft_vorbisdec.so
libstagefright_soft_vpxdec.so
libstagefright_soft_vpxenc.so
libstagefright_wfd.so
libstagefright_xmlparser.so
libstdc++.so
libsurfaceflinger.so
libsurfaceflinger_ddmconnection.so
libsuspend.so
libsync.so
libsysutils.so
libtextclassifier.so
libtextclassifier_hash.so
libtinyxml2.so
libtombstoned_client.so
libui.so
libunwind.so
libusbhost.so
libutils.so
libvintf.so
libvixl-arm.so
libvixl-arm64.so
libvndksupport.so
libvorbisidec.so
libvulkan.so
libwebviewchromium_loader.so
libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
libwifi-service.so
libwilhelm.so
libxml2.so
libz.so
libziparchive.so
```

Comment: Did you look into the NDK?